# Contact functionality for Mailing's

Tags: apex, contact

I am evaluating code in my Salesforce Instance. I stumbled across some code in which is on Contact. With that said I am unsure of what MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingPostalCode, MailingState and MailingCountry is... I found that these fields can be found in the Developer Console however what are they used for and how are they populated?

```
 for(Contact i : Trigger.New){

  //If the old mailing street not = new mailing steet and currenct mailing is not null then assisng mailing steet to address. 
  //Else if contact is updated and address doesnt match new update address then assign mailingsteet as address c
if( (Trigger.oldMap.get(i.id).MailingStreet != i.MailingStreet) && i.MailingStreet != '') 
  i.Address__c = i.MailingStreet;
else if(Trigger.oldMap.get(i.id).Address__c != i.Address__c)  
  i.MailingStreet = i.Address__c;

if( (Trigger.oldMap.get(i.id).MailingCity != i.MailingCity) && i.MailingCity != '') 
  i.City__c = i.MailingCity;
else if (Trigger.oldMap.get(i.id).City__c != i.City__c)
  i.MailingCity = i.City__c;

if( (Trigger.oldMap.get(i.id).MailingPostalCode != i.MailingPostalCode) && i.MailingPostalCode != '') 
  i.Zip_Postal_Code__c = i.MailingPostalCode;
else if (Trigger.oldMap.get(i.id).Zip_Postal_Code__c != i.Zip_Postal_Code__c)
  i.MailingPostalCode = i.Zip_Postal_Code__c;

if( (Trigger.oldMap.get(i.id).MailingState != i.MailingState) && i.MailingState != '') 
  i.State_Province__c = i.MailingState;
else if (Trigger.oldMap.get(i.id).State_Province__c != i.State_Province__c)
  i.MailingState = i.State_Province__c;

if( (Trigger.oldMap.get(i.id).MailingCountry != i.MailingCountry) && i.MailingCountry != '') 
  i.Country__c = i.MailingCountry;
else if (Trigger.oldMap.get(i.id).Country__c != i.Country__c)
  i.MailingCountry = i.Country__c;

 }

}
```

Comment: These are [standard fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Contact.htm) on Contact. They store address details and are part of the compound `MailingAddress` field. Different orgs will use them in different ways.

Comment: O i didnt see that as a field on the page layout and i didnt think to look since that was not a field on the object. Thanks